Modify command for sum so that substack unnecessary
Is there a way to modify sum so that \sum_{...} behaves as \sum_{\substack{...}}? It is of course possible to have a command containing the underscore, but I'm interested in if the underscore can be preserved.

Are you able and willing to compile your document with LuaLaTeX?

I think something like this should work. My guess is it will break something...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\origsum}{\sum}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\sum}{e{_^}}{%
  \origsum
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\substack{#1}}}
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}
  }

\begin{document}

$abc\sum^\infty_{x\in X} def\sum_{x\in X\\ x\in X}^\infty ghi$

\[abc\sum_{x\in X}^\infty def\sum_{x\in X\\ x\in X}^\infty ghi\]

\end{document}


